# Eclipse - where is the java option?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Trying to install eclipse CDT C/C++ in ubuntu 10.04, gets into some troubles.
While trying to install CDT plugin in eclipse " “.jar has been tampered!” are prompted in Eclipse."
I found this link, which can explain the issue, becuase I have jre7 installed in ubuntu.
so I tried to follow the instruction in this link, which suggest to move back to jre6 instead of jre7
http://www.mkyong.com/google-app-engine/google-plugin-for-eclipse-jar-has-been-tampered/

But in eclipse window->preferences, I just can't find any java option, in the menu. I have totally different options than the one that appear in the above link. I only see General, Help, Install/Update, Run/Debug and Team. Can anyone help me on this issue ?

Thanks
Ran

Comment: You probably have a version of Eclipse which does not have the Java Development Tools installed.

Comment: I would say you need to run Eclipse with Java 6 not "Change the JRE used when launching Java application in debug/run mode".

Answer (score 1):

The CDT Project provides a fully functional C and C++ Integrated Development. For Java development, download the relevant package from https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install eclipse CDT in ubuntu.You can install it by executing following command on command prompt.

Try this

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse-cdt
```

Above command works only if you have eclipse previously installed.If this is the first time you want to install eclipse and straight install it with cdt the you do

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse eclipse-cdt
```